# Perfect construction in a complement

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, perfect-constructions, perfect-aspect

According to @StoneyB's [Cannonical Post #2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it) . States cannot serve as the complement in Wh-cleft constructions. As an example there,

> - What John did was have written three novels. – *This is not idiomatic English*

But what disturb my mind is, what if the state serve as the complement in this kind of sentence

> All John did was have written three novels.

Is this sentence grammatical and idiomatic?

Comment: What are you trying to say? What do you want this sentence to mean?

Comment: @Catija Im just asking about the construction and they sentences was copied from the cannonical post. Do you think the second sentence grammatical?

Comment: Neither one is grammatical or idiomatic.  At a minimum, you need a "to" in front of "have".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that.  You have to do this:

> What John had done was write three novels

I *think* what's happening is that only infinitives (and in this case *to* is not specified) are valid after *to be*.

Comment: What about the second sentence, should it be *"All John had done was write three novels"*?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express state, then you'd need something like "John's entire (creative output / life's work) was 3 novels".  If you explicitly use a verb, you're no longer expressing state:  "The only thing John ever did was write 3 novels".

Comment: Hrmm.. stuck at that *"creative output"*.. I still dont get it.